# How do we get these Cassandra Data to a Gridview in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, gridview, cassandra, cassandra-sharp

I am using the `CassandraSharp`, How do we get these `Cassandra` Data to a Gridview in VB.net

There are data in the table. But the grid is empty. If I use response.write, i get to see the data from the data

```
    pConStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("cassandra")
    connectionString = pConStr.ConnectionString
    Dim sSQL As String = "select col1, col2, col3, col4 from tab1;"
    Using CQLConn As New CqlConnection(connectionString)
    CQLConn.Open()
    Dim CQLCmd As New CqlCommand(CQLConn, sSQL)
    Dim CQLdr As CqlDataReader
    CQLdr = OraCmd.ExecuteReader()
    gridview1.datasource=CQLdr
    gridview1.databind()
    End Using
```

Comment: So...have you tried anything?

Comment: I have updated the code above..I tried to use (fluentCassandra, Cassandraemon and Datastax drivers). But none of them are useful. My intention, to show the data in Gridview using VB.net. I get the below error values array too small to fit row contents Parameter name: values
at CqlSharp.CqlDataReader.GetValues(Object[] values) at System.Data.Common.DbEnumerator.MoveNext()